# Can I generate client code using SpringFox?

Tags: jhipster, openapi, swagger-codegen, springfox, openapi-generator

I am trying to determine if it is possible to generate client code / stubs (in C#) for my API. The API back-end has largely been generated using JHipster, and is Spring based. It is already configured to use SpringFox for generating documentation (and that works nicely).

I admit that I don't have a good understanding of how all these pieces and parts fit together. A lot of this is new to me. As I understand it, SpringFox builds its documentation from the API itself by interrogating the code. And I understand that Swagger/OpenAPI is able to generate client code using the CodeGen projects. So it seems it should be possible to combine SpringFox and CodeGen to generate client code from the server code, but I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible, what have you tried so far? have you read https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#to-generate-a-sample-client-library . You must use swagger-codegen 2.x

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou. It seems Swagger CodeGen needs a JSON file as input. I'm struggling to understand how to get that file from SpringFox. If I can get that, I can probably work out the CodeGen side of the equation.

Comment: Not only a file, a URL works the same. Start your JHipster app and point swagger-codegen to `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs`  (assuming you use default port)

Comment: I was able to get that to work @GaëlMarziou. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it working